# Javascript function is not returning saved value in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, closures

Here is the code:

```
app.service("dataShareSvc", ['$rootScope', 'parserUIDataModel', function($rootScope, parserUIDataModel) {

    // defaults
    this._parserDataLoad = [];

    return {
        loadParserDataLoad: function (pidId, pidRuleId) {
            parserUIDataModel.listParserRules(pidId, pidRuleId, 'y').then(function(data) {
                this._parserDataLoad = data;
            });
        },
        getParserDataLoad: function () {
            return this._parserDataLoad;
        },
    };

}]);
```

The issue I encounter is when I call **loadParserDataLoad** it does assign nonempty to **this._parserDataLoad**.

However, when later I call **getParserDataLoad**, the value of **this._parserDataLoad** appears to be empty array. There was no manipulation of that variable in between. Why is that happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Fix it using a clousure:

```
app.service("dataShareSvc", ['$rootScope', 'parserUIDataModel', function($rootScope, parserUIDataModel) {

    // defaults

    this._parserDataLoad = [];
    var that = this;

    return {
        loadParserDataLoad: function (pidId, pidRuleId) {

            parserUIDataModel.listParserRules(pidId, pidRuleId, 'y').then(function(data) {
                that._parserDataLoad = data;
            });
        },
        getParserDataLoad: function () {
            return that._parserDataLoad;
        },
    };

}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`module.service` expects a constructor. In general a constructor is not supposed to return anything (Yes, I know there are lots of examples that do). So your code should actually be `app.factory`, not `app.service`.

At the time the constructor function is called, `this` refers to the instance that was created by calling the constructor with `new`. But your constructor returns something, which essentially means that the instance is discarded. This also means that `this._parserDataLoad` gets lost entirely.

And last but not least in `this._parserDataLoad = data;`, `this` refers to something completely different anyway. In this case to `window`.

The same is true for `return this._parserDataLoad`. Here `this` refers to the object that the constructor has returned.

The easiest fix is to get rid of `this`:

```
var _parserDataLoad = [];
...
_parserDataLoad = data;
...
```